# RODBC sqlSave(..., fast = FALSE) - "RODBCTypeInfo" not available for .Call() for package "RODBC"

Tags: r, odbc, rodbc

My `sqlSave` query which *works perfectly* with `fast = TRUE` fails with the following error with `fast = FALSE` (connecting to MS `.accdb`):

```
> db <- odbcConnectAccess2007(PATH_OUT)
> sqlSave(db, df, "tblTest", rownames = F, append = T, fast = F)
Error in .Call("RODBCTypeInfo", attr(channel, "handle_ptr"), as.integer(type),  : 
  "RODBCTypeInfo" not available for .Call() for package "RODBC"

> traceback()
4: .Call("RODBCTypeInfo", attr(channel, "handle_ptr"), as.integer(type), 
       PACKAGE = "RODBC")
3: sqlTypeInfo(channel)
2: sqlwrite(channel, tablename, dat, verbose = verbose, fast = fast, 
       test = test, nastring = nastring)
1: sqlSave(db, df, "tblTest", rownames = F, append = T, fast = F)
```

I don't understand the error message myself, so any ideas why?

(I was simply trying to test how much slower `fast = FALSE` would be)

Comment: also having the same error because of fast = FALSE. couldn't figure out the reason though. it may be a bug in RODBC.

Comment: I have the same problem now, fine with fast=TRUE, but fails with above error message with falst=TRUE